# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Error:
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/runner/PyBot/cogs/music.py", line 35, in play
vc.play(source)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'
```

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class Music(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  @commands.command()
  async def join(self,ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel!")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

  @commands.command()
  async def disconnected(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

  @commands.command()
  async def play(self,ctx,url):
    #ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': 'vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,**FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)

  @commands.command()
  async def pause(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    await ctx.send("Paused ⏸")

  @commands.command()
  async def resume(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.resume()
    await ctx.send("Resume ▶️")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Music(client))
```

Comment: The simple answer is that `ctx.voice_client` is `None`, so `vc` is `None`. It is called out in the documentation as potentially being `None`, presumably when no voice client is available. You should handle that situation.

Comment: just create a instance like if not VC: pass else:VC.play(sec) it will automatically pass the none situation